# Prevent keyboard reset when BasicTextField value changes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use compose for my UI. One of the input fields has an input mask, such as "A00–00–000000" ("A" stands for any letter, "0" stands for any digit). This means that if the user types in "X123" I change field value to "X12-3". If he types in "XX" I change it to "X" and so on.

**It mostly works fine, but there is one problem:** whenever I change `BasicTextField` `value` programatically, keyboard is reset back to it's initial state.

The field accepts both letters and numbers. This means that when the user first opens the keyboard, it is opened with letters keyboard. User can manually switch it to numbers&symbols, but as soon as you change value programatically, keyboard will revert to letters. Which makes typing very annoying.

Minimal code that allows to reproduce this issue:

```
val randomText = remember { mutableStateOf("123") }
BasicTextField(
    value = randomText.value,
    onValueChange = { randomText.value = it }
)
Button(
    onClick = {
        randomText.value = (Math.random() * 100).roundToInt().toString()
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Randomize")
}
```

Start typing, change keyboard type to numbers and then press the "Randomize" button. Keyboard type will get reset.

Here's how it looks:
[image: Keyboard reset when you change value programatically]

How can you prevent keyboard from resetting to default mode when you set `value` on `BasicTextField`?